Why does Dell monitor connected to Mac Air go into a "deep" sleep?
I am using a MacBook Air (M1) which is connected to a Dell monitor via [Monitor]VGA -> [Laptop]USBC in "extension mode" (non-mirroring mode). If I don't use the monitor for some time, it goes into sleep mode and I can't wake it up except by unplugging the USBC and replugging it again. How to avoid this problem?

What do you mean by "don't use the monitor"? Are you using the computer during that time, or is it idling?

I mean when I go for a coffee break and come back, I find both laptop and the monitor in sleep mode. Now pressing a (mac) keyboard key does wakes up my laptop but not the monitor. I have to unplug the usb and then replug to get it work again.

Does the monitor have a VGA input only?

Yes, unfortunately.

Does the monitor wake up when you switch the computer on? Or are you manually switching the monitor on at that time?
